# Define a script's src in a new line

Tags: html

I want to use clipboard.min.js for my website, my website builder only allows me to insert scripts as such:

```
<script>
insert whatever here
</script>
```

I want to make it so that I can define the script src so that it can use clipboard.min.js but the only way that I know how to do so is inline:

```
<script src="scriptdirectory/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any way I would be able to define the script in the first format specified above?

Comment: What website builder you are using? Probably there is an option to point to an external JavaScript file.

Comment: Using Zyro web builder